# get an older version of a lib with git

Tags: git

I have upgraded a lib that I use in Android with Git, and now, it appears that my code doesn't work anymore.

I tried to get back to an old version with : Reverse current branch to this commit ( SourceTree ) and Pull, but I get this message.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
README.md
build.gradle
demo/AndroidManifest.xml
demo/build.gradle
gradle.properties
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
library/AndroidManifest.xml
library/build.gradle
library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java
library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/ViewDragHelper.java
maven_push.gradle
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How should I do???

Comment: Stash or commit your changes.  Git doesn't want to destroy what work it thinks you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Git thinks you've made changes to those files, if you want to throw away any changes you've made run `git checkout .` or if you'd like to save them for later you can run `git stash`.

If you choose to stash your changes you can retrieve them later by running `git stash pop`.

Also, to go back to an old version you won't need to pull again as you already have the repo on your local machine. Instead you will need to checkout the branch or commit of the version you want.